# Ansible yum disablerepo does not work if repo is not installed

Tags: ansible, yum

I have a number of different Centos7 servers running. I like to use ansible to update them all at once.

As one of my servers has an additional repository enabled, which I do not want to update. I've added to the playbook the option to disable this repo. This works as expected.

However, on my other servers, I did not install and enable this repo. When using the disablerepo in my ansible playbook, I get an error: repository not found.

How do I solve this in the ansible-playbook? Is it possible to add an condition like, if repo installed; then disablerepo; else do nothing?

Is it possible to ignore these errors?

ansible-playbook:

```
---
- hosts: [all]
  tasks:
- name: update all packages to lastest version
  yum:
    name: '*'
    state: latest
    disablerepo: sernet-samba-4.2
```

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_error_handling.html

Comment: But this is an XY Problem. Don't manage your servers by relying on their state. Declare what state each server should have and don't run tasks destined to fail.

Answer (score 0):

you can put `ignore_errors: yes` as in the [link](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_error_handling.html) from the comment, or you can put [when](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html), only if certain package is installed, sure you have to register them to variables first, I'm thinking something like:

```
- name: check if installed
  shell: rpm -qa sernet-samba-4.2
  register: is_installed

- name: update all packages to lastest version
  yum:
    name: '*'
    state: latest
    disablerepo: sernet-samba-4.2
  when: is_installed.rc == 1
```

Warning: Untested.